# How can I bind json array stored in a model to a list control in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an Employees JSON containing a JSON array

```
{
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
.........
```

I have bounded it to a model and set it to view.

```
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.loadData("Employees.json");
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Code for binding data to List:

```
    <List id="list" items="{/Employees.json}">
      <content>
       <Label text="{userId}">
     </content>
    </List>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the documentation and found that we can access keys using path:

```
<List id="test-list" items="{
    path   : '/Employees', 
    sorter : [{
        path       : 'userId', 
        descending : true
    }]
}">
    <StandardListItem title="{jobTitleName}"  />
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

or this should good if sorting is not needed

```
<List id="test-list" items="{/Employees}">
    <StandardListItem title="{jobTitleName}"  />
</List>
```